# How to scrape information from websites with subframes

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I am trying to build a simple web scraper to extract flight information from the student Universe.

I used the selenium to navigate the webpages to get the flight information for my desired location and date. There is no problem for me to get to the right page with all the information.
However, I have difficulties in extracting the information from the webpage. I used xpath to locate those elements that contain desired info, but extracting the information is unsuccessful unless I manually scroll up and down the webpage. It seems that this has something to do with subframes embedded in the website. I tried to iterate all the iframe to see if I get information with the command driver.switch_to.frame(), but the problem remains.

It would be great if anyone could offer some help regarding how to scrape information from websites like this. The problem may not be caused by the existence of subframe. any input is appreciated. 
The code I used to extract flights info is shown below, an article tag contains all the info(carrier name, departure time,arrival time and so on). What I did first is to locate this element.

```
    def parseprice(driver):
        driver.maximize_window()
        parser = lxml.html.fromstring(driver.page_source,driver.current_url)
        flights=parser.xpath('//article[@class="itin activeCheck"]') 
        driver.quit()
        carriername=flights[0].xpath('//p[@id="airlineName0"]/text()')
        duration=flights[0].xpath('//strong[@id="duration0"]/text()')
        depttime=flights[0].xpath('//span[@id="departureTime0"]/text()')
        arrtime=flights[0].xpath('//span[@id="arrivalTime0"]/text()')
        price=flights[0].xpath('//p[@ng-click="pricePoint()"]//text()')
        stops=flights[0].xpath('//p[@id="stops0"]//text()')
        stoplis=list()
        for st in stops:
            res1=re.search('^(\d)+\D*',st)
            if res1 is not None:
                stoplis.append(int(res1.group(1)))
        now=datetime.datetime.now()
        now=now.timetuple()
        for i in range(20):
        yield{'current time':str(now[1])+'/'+str(now[2])+'/'+str(now[0]),'carrier':carriername[i],'duration':duration[i],'price':price[i],'numstops':stoplis[i],'departure_time':depttime[i],'arrival_time':arrtime[i]}
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the code that you have done? Based on what you described, it sounds like, the data you want to extract is actually loaded using ajax (thus, you failed to get it in the first try).

Comment: Hi, the code I used to extract the desired info is shown above. I am not sure if the webpage uses Ajax as the webpage is not loading contents in the way we see on Instagram or other websites that use Ajax. Thanks for your help!

Comment: no prob. but, would it be possible for you to show all the code? (at least, where I am able to reproduce the case).

Comment: All the code I used to scrape the information is shown above. I even tried to maximize the window or scroll down to imitate the actions users would take. However, I could not get the info unless I manually browse the page(scroll up and down)

Comment: ummm.... could you give me the link to the website? I would like to see it

Comment: Sure, the website I would like to scrape is https://www.studentuniverse.com. The argument passed to the function above is a webdriver object with the page open that displays flight information for a particular combination of departure and arrival city.